# How to find all possible cycle notations for finite element set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, algorithms

For 4 element set(say ${P,O,S,T}$) all possible cycle notations are:

```
(12)
(13)
(14)
(23)
(24)
(34)
(123)
(132)
(124)
(142)
(134)
(143)
(234)
(243)
(1234)
(1243)
(1423)
(1324)
(1342)
(1432)
```

---

For 7 element set(say $R,E,P,L,A,Y,S$), one possible cycle notation is:

```
   (1875)(23)(4)(6)
```

---

1. What is an algorithm to find all possible cycle notations for n element set?
2. Is every cycle notation a product of disjoint cycles? because I learnt that every permutation is a product of disjoint cycles.

Comment: 1) Iterate over all $n!$ permutations in whatever your favorite way to do so and compute the cycle decomposition for each. There is no point being efficient since $n!$ grows too quickly to be useful. If you only want cycle notations up to "isomorphism", then you want to iterate over all integer partitions of $n$, which is usually done with recursive backtracking. 2) Yes, by definition; this is part of showing it's well-defined.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Am just trying to find the efficient way to generate all possible permutations using cycle notations

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson Every permutation can be written as product of transpositions

Comment: You have only listed 20 permutations of the 4-element set, and there are 24 of them, so you must have missed four of them out!

Comment: @DerekHolt Can you add those missing? Am sorry

Comment: Well there is $(1,2)(3,4)$ and two more like that. I will leave you to find the final one.

Comment: @user1787812 Certainly every permutation can be written as a product of transpositions. That does not seem relevant since you appeared to be using "cycle notation" to mean "disjoint cycle decomposition". If you're just trying to iterate over all permutations, it's much better to do so directly than to use cycle notation.

Answer (score 2):

In SageMath, you can do

```
sage: for si in Permutations(4):
....:     print(si.cycle_string())
....:     
()
(3,4)
(2,3)
(2,3,4)
(2,4,3)
(2,4)
(1,2)
(1,2)(3,4)
(1,2,3)
(1,2,3,4)
(1,2,4,3)
(1,2,4)
(1,3,2)
(1,3,4,2)
(1,3)
(1,3,4)
(1,3)(2,4)
(1,3,2,4)
(1,4,3,2)
(1,4,2)
(1,4,3)
(1,4)
(1,4,2,3)
(1,4)(2,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by dividing, $S_n$ in conjugacy class and that depends on the partitions of the number $n$.
If you are taking about $S_7$,

Then first partition the number $7$

And all the possibilities are $(7),(6+1),(5+2),(5+1+1),(4+3),(4+2+1),(4+1+1+1),(3+3+1),(3+2+2),(3+2+1+1),(3+1+1+1+1),(2+2+2+1),(2+2+1+1+1),(2+1+1+1+1+1),(1+1+1+1+1+1+1) $.

You can see there are $15$ different classes that means there are possiblity of $15$ different type of cycle notation.

For the partition $(7)$, there be cycles like $(1 2 3 4 5 6 7), (1 3 2 4 5 7 6)$ etc. , which are of full length $7$.

For the partition $(1+1+1+1+1+1+1) $, only identity permutation is there , which is cycle of length $1$,

Similarly, for the partition $(2+1+1+1+1+1) $ , there are $(1 2), (3 4), (6 7)$ etc.

For, partition $(2+2+1+1+1) $ , $(1 2)(3 4), (4 5)(6 7)$ etc.

**Edit**: for $n=4$, after partitioning the number $4$, the all possibilities are $(4),(3+1),(2+2),(2+1+1),(1+1+1+1)$.

For the partition $(4)$, there are $\frac{4!}{4^1 1!} = 6 $ , cycles, which are $(1234),(1324),(1243),(2134),(1423),(1432)$.

For the partition $(3+1)$, there are $\frac{4!}{3^{1}1^{1} 1! 1!} =8 $ cycles, which are $(123),(132),(234),(243),(134),(143),(124),(142)$.

For the partition $(2+2)$, there are $\frac{4!}{2^2 2!}= 3 $ cycles, which are $(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)$.

For the partition $(2+1+1)$, there are $\frac{4!}{2^{1}1^{2} 1! 2!}= 6 $ cycles, which are $(12),(13),(14),(23),(24),(34)$.

For the partition $(1+1+1+1)$, there are $\frac{4!}{1^4 4!}= 1 $ cycles, which is identity permutation.

Comment: I think permutation is more like partitioning problem.

Comment: By this partitioning, you can get idea about how many are there different cycle forms ? Also, you can calculate them, that's the beauty of this partitioning. And , moreover, it's really hard to write all the cycles for bigger $n$, partitioning $n$ , gives many clarification!!

Comment: Check this video about counting partitions.... https://youtu.be/DvgT4dnSMVM

Comment: Hmm, that's what I am taking about.

Comment: For , counting case, there are more videos,,,but in different language from english.

Comment: Also, you can find it in the standard book " Abstract algebra by Dummit & Foote " and also , many more details.

Comment: Am learning abstract algebra from here.... https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLL0ATV5XYF8AQZuEYPnVwpiFy0jEipqN-

Comment: Are you completed all basic parts. I think you can also go for some good books on this.

Comment: I have completed 25 videos in this. This is University class discussion.

Comment: Ok, of course good,, but books are books!! Not only to learn, also make you , how to apply them,, how to think more of them, etc.

Comment: Can you please comment on this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3797803/407297)